# What is the home directory for JDK?

Tags: java

I am having a problem in selecting home directory for JDK. Even though I have selected the following path: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_91", it keeps showing the error: "The selected directory is not a valid home for JDK". My java folder has two folders- bin and lib.
[Window for selecting home directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFyEO.png)

Kindly help me in selecting home directory.
Thank you!

Comment: What are you selecting it in? It isn't clear what tool that is from the screenshot. Please indicate it in your question and add an appropriate tag as well.

Comment: You are selecting a Java JRE folder and I suspect that your IDE is looking for a JDK.  That being said, do you have a JDK installed?

Comment: The path you have provided is "java runtime environment" which is for java virtual machine .install java from here and you jdk path will be like "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin"

Comment: IntelliJ is asking you for a JDK not a JRE. So you have to download and install a proper JDK.

Answer (score 7):

You have currently located a JRE, or Java Runtime Environment. That does indeed contain a `java` executable and can launch JVMs, but it's not made for development, rather more as a "Java client". For example if you look into it's `/bin` folder, you won't find the `javac` executable needed to compile.

What you need is a JDK, or Java Development Toolkit. It contains all the JRE contains, with additional tools for development. You can find it for download on the [Oracle website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

Comment: Thank you there. I downloaded the link there and the important thing that i found out was setting the location so that our system can know where our compiler is. To set the path follow this : Control Panel\System and Security\System. Now click advanced system settings and then Environment variables. There in the variable name we must set it as : "Path" and Variable value as "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_12\bin" and then click ok. 

Now home directory for jdk will be: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_12\bin".

Answer (score 0):

Your home directory will jdk not jre. If your jdk is installed properly then there will be a jdk folder. Try setting C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin

Answer (score -3):

try this on windows to know the home of your jdk

```
c:\> for %i in (java.exe) do @echo.   %~$PATH:i
```

Answer (score -4):

Your home directory for JDK would be `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin"`

Comment: His home directory for his "JDK" is a path to a "JRE"? Interesting.